# getting gibberish text while Exporting Html table to Excel file using PHPExcel library

Tags: php, jquery, html, phpexcel, codeigniter-3

below is my php code

```
$html = $this->load->view('engine-status-resp', $data, true); // table
$tmpfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'html');
file_put_contents($tmpfile, utf8_decode($html));

$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($tmpfile);

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="your_name.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($doc, 'Excel5');
$writer->save('php://output');
```

When i try to move the excel file to a folder like

```
$writer->save($outputFileName);
```

it works fine i get a excel file in a folder. But when i use

```
$writer->save('php://output');
```

it gives some gibbersih text in ajax response instead of forcing downloadof the excel file

```
 ÐÏà¡±á;þÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿþÿÿÿþÿÿÿ!"#þÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿþÿàòùOh«+'³Ù0¸@Hh¤°äUntitled SpreadsheetUnknowncreatorUnknown Creator@5Ô@5Ô »
```

ÌÑB°=¼%r8X"1ÜCalibriàõÿ À àõÿ À àõÿ À àõÿ À àõÿ À àõÿ À àõÿ À àõÿ À àõÿ À àõÿ À àõÿ À àõÿ À àõÿ À àõÿ À àõÿ À à À  ÿâ8ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÀÀÀÿ3fÿÿÌÌÿÿffÿfÌÌÌÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÌÿÌÿÿÌÿÌÿÿÌÿÿÌÌÿÿÌ3fÿ3ÌÌÌÿÌÿÿfff3f3f33333f33333TWorksheetÁÁgæ®üHSl NoRunning TimeIdleTime Time  Stop TimeCount Of StopsDistance TravelledAverage Speed    Maxeed08:30:02NA15:29:58  568.9 Kms16.76 Kmph   62.8 Kmph»
ÌÑ*+Á&ffffffæ?'ffffffæ?(è?)è?"dXX333333Ó?333333Ó?U}$ }$  }$  }$  }$  }$  }$  }$     ýý
ý
ý
ý
ý
ý
ý
ð?ý
ý
 ý

ÀR@ý
ý
ý

> ¶@ddggÿÿÿÿÿ
>   þÿÕÍÕ.+,ù®0¼HPX`hp
>   xä
>   WorksheetFeuilles de calculRoot Entryÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÀF5Ô5Ô    SummaryInformation(ÿÿÿÿ ÀFèWorkbookÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ  ÀFØDocumentSummaryInformation8ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÀF ìþÿÿÿþÿÿÿþÿÿÿýÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ

I have even tried converting html to array and then exporting to excel, that also resulted in the same.[array to excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424847/export-an-array-of-arrays-to-excell-in-php)
  [table to excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24048291/how-to-export-html-table-to-excel-using-phpexcel)

Comment: It's more about downloading file with Ajax. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax.

Comment: fyi: PhpExcel is deprecated

Comment: yes iam using a very old phpexcel is there an alternative to the phpexcel library?

Comment: you can't download files using AJAX. That just gives you some binary data in a JS variable, it doesn't send the file to the user's disk. Use a standard HTTP request instead.

Comment: but i have all the table data coming in ajax response , i have to write all the functionality again to have a seperate http request.is there a way to handle downloads on ajax?